# How would schools differ in a world with superhumans?

Tags: society, super-powers, education

How would schools differ from schools of today if people had powers like telekinesis, elemental mimicry or manipulation, enhanced speed or strength, etc?

In my story, superhumans have been around for almost a century. The location is the United States and the time period is around 2100.

Superhumans are basically a mixture of Marvels X-Men and Inhumans. They gain their powers around puberty and those powers originate from an alien-like race.

A select number have superpowers. In my story about 11.2 billion people live in the world and 25% of that are superhumans.

For how there viewed by society is difficult. Superhumans are see in many ways, they are feared and hatred by some, and others see them as equals .

Once children discover they have powers they are relocated to Super-Academies/Schools. Super-Academies teach subjects like science, math, language arts, et cetera.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Writer-Chan. It would be better to ask one question at a time and to provide some background. For now we no almost nothing about _your_ superhumans. For example, are superhumans previously humans, are they aliens, time travelers, etc. Are they posthumans?

Comment: Please take the time to take our [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and read about what makes a [good question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  As written, this question will be closed as too broad.  You've basically asked us to write your entire story.  Worse, without knowing anything about your superhumans, you've asked us to tell you where they come from ("primarily opinion-based") and what wars were fought because of them ("too story-based").

Comment: "Societies with superhumans" can generally be classified into 2 types: the ones where society can keep its "super" members in check without all-out war, and the ones that can't. I feel you are talking about the latter type, although in year 2100 technology should be able to do much more.

Comment: I suggest adding some information about the status of superhumans in your society, i.e. are they accepted as 'regular' members of society, are they criminals, or something else. Your school curriculum will depend on this as well.

Comment: Will every person gain powers at puberty or just a select few? If the latter, are schools mixed between normal kids and those who will turn superhuman or not?

Comment: In the real world there are many different types of schools. Which type of school are you asking about?

Comment: An school that teaches all grades and students live in dorms.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your question is a little vague, but I'm going to point you at My Hero Academia. It started out as a manga (comic) and then got adapted into an anime (with pretty good English dub to boot)

Most people there have superpowers of some sort, ranging from minor stuff like light telekinesis to mind control or control of elemental fire. There are tons and tons of different powers listed/take part in the story, and the author tried pretty hard to make a lot of them unconventional. The story centers on a kid who didn't have a power gaining one and then going to superhero school and eventually getting a job as a "professional hero", which is somewhere inbetween a police officer and a mercenary. There are also villains of all flavors as you'd expect